# Duplicate "id" column with DBFlow tables and Stetho

Tags: android, orm, annotations, dbflow, stetho

I'm writing an application for Android using DBFlow as ORM library. So, here is one of my tables model:

```
@Table(database = Database.class)
public class Language extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    long id;

    @Column
    String key;

    @Column
    String title;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /* .. Other setters and getters .. */
}
```

Everything works pretty good, but when I take a look at my DB inspector (I'm using [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)), I can see 2 identical "id" column:

[image]

Its a little bit embarrassing and redundantly.. Isn't it? Is it OK, and what is the cause of this behavior? And if it is not OK, how can I do it right?

Comment: in most of the db tool one more column shown is an row id which shows row count i am not sure which tool u using to browse db you can check by deleting any row form top and check that both id values are identical or different

Comment: You are incredibly right, it seems like it's a Stetho feature :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, looks like its Stetho-side feature/bug (according [this issue](https://github.com/requery/requery/issues/12#issuecomment-187583649)). Just ignore it in production.